# How to play consecutive songs with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

On the front end, there is a selection box and a music player.

Here is my **html**, with help from Salvo Nostrato:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Test </title>
      <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
      <script src="whatToPlay.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onload();">
        <select id="changeselection" name="change-selection">
            <option id="change1" value="change1" selected>Song 1</option>
            <option id="change2" value="change2">Song 2</option>
            <option id="change3" value="change3">Song 3</option>
        </select>

        <audio id="audio1" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg" controls preload>
            <source id="audiochange" type="audio/mp3" src="audio/default.mp3">
                Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>

    </body>
  </html>
```

and my **whatToPlay.js** file, with help from Salvo Nostrato (**jQuery**):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#changeselection").on("change",function(){

    audio=$("#audio1");
    $("#audio1").attr("src",src);

    if($(this).val()=="change2"){
      var src = "audio/song2.mp3";
      console.log('change2');
    }

    else if ($(this).val()=="change3"){
      var src = "audio/song3.mp3";
      console.log('change3');
    }  

    else {
      var src = "audio/default.mp3";
      console.log('change1');
    }

    audio=$("#audio1");
    $("#audio1").attr("src",src);


    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
    audio[0].play();

  });
});
```

*When I select Song 2 (id="change2"), I want to play audio/song2.mp3, and then when that ends, I want audio/song2A.mp3 to play immediately. How do I minimally add this to my code?*

Comment: Look for [`onend` event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette But where should I add this in my jQuery file if I want audio/song2A.mp3 to come before just audio/song2.mp3 when Song 2 (id="change2") is selected? I don't want it to affect any of the other options.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an event handler for the `ended` event.

Here is something I typed quite fast... Whithout testing it.
But comments should be helpfull on the idea.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Lookup for the audio element
  var audio = $("#audio1");

  // Lookup for the select element
  var audioChange = $("#changeselection");

  // Create an audio source array
  var audioSources = [
    "audio/default.mp3",
    "audio/song2.mp3",
    "audio/song3.mp3"
  ];

  // Select change handler
  audioChange.on("change",function(){

    if($(this).val()=="change2"){
      var src = audioSources[1];
      console.log('change2');
    }

    else if ($(this).val()=="change3"){
      var src = audioSources[2];
      console.log('change3');
    }  

    else {
      var src = audioSources[0];
      console.log('change1');
    }

    // Step 1 - Pause the playing audio
    audio[0].pause();

    // Step 2 - Change the audio source using what the above contitions determined.
    audio.attr("src",src);

    // Step 3 - Load this new source
    audio[0].load();

    // Step 4 - Play!
    audio[0].play();

  });

  // Song ended handler
  audio.on("ended", function() {

    // Find what has just ended
    var whichEnded = $(this).attr("src");

    // Find its index in the array
    var thisSrcIndex = audioSources.indexOf(whichEnded);

    // If last index, set it to -1
    if(thisSrcIndex==audioSources.length-1){
      thisSrcIndex = -1;
    }

    // increment the index
    thisSrcIndex++;

    // Same steps as in the other handler here...

    // Step 2 - Change the audio source using what the above contitions determined.
    audio.attr("src",audioSources[thisSrcIndex]);

    // Step 3 - Load this new source
    audio[0].load();

    // Step 4 - Play!
    audio[0].play();
  });

});
```

Comment: No, it's not that I want to add a song after Song 2 in a sequence. It's like this: on the HTML webpage, there is a drop-down for a selection of Song 1, Song 2, and Song 3. However, when the user selects Song 2, I want the Song 2 file to play, followed immediately by Song 2A. When Song 1 is selected, I want only Song 1 to play, and when Song 3 is selected, I want only Song 3 to play.

Comment: So, it would be the same logic... But you'll have to define more arrays. Like an array for "playlist" #2 like `["audio/song2A.mp3","audio/song2B.mp3"]`... The idea is to check what has ended to determine what's next.

Comment: Is this [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cpb4ksxj/1/) what you mean? *(It didn't work)*

Comment: *(The player did not update/change songs when I chose a different selection from the drop-down, or there was something wrong with the audioSources part of the code.)*

Comment: [**Here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/gRgoON?editors=1011) it is. The sounds I've used are horrible... lol But this is working.

Comment: I see that it works in codepen.io but for some reason even when using your code, on my browser when I select a different song from the drop-down it doesn't play a different sound file. It is stuck playing the same file (Crowd Boo). I am using Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95

Comment: Do you have a live link ? Because I can't tell.

Comment: *(It continues to play the default file even if I select a different song)*

Comment: I don't have anywhere to host the files, but I tried running it on jsfiddle.net and it seems to work, I just don't know why it doesn't work on the browser running the files directly. Could any part of the code be incompatible with Chrome?

Comment: Look for errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337). I can't help more.

Comment: How do you make it so that the playlist does not loop after it is done playing?

Comment: I added a looping "switch" in this second [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/pwRaoL?editors=1011) ;)